# Error when compiling (pdfLaTeX)

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, format-files

I wrote some lines and I wanted to view the pdf, so I compiled and built but I have  this error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
pdflatex.EXE: The memory dump file could not be found.
pdflatex.EXE: Data: pdflatex.fmt
texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).
```

Can you help me to correct this error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: You can try to regenerate the format files (`initexmf --dump`) or just the format for pdfLaTeX (`initexmf --dump=pdflatex`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you tell me where i have to write this please?

Comment: The command line. Alternative, Start->Programs->MiKTeX 2.9->Maintenance->Settings and "Update Formats", see [documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/configuring.html) with [screenshot](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/images/mo-general.png).

Comment: Encountered a similar problem ...
Error disappeared when I ran the same command with Admin privileges.
After that, things seem to work even without Admin on, guess it was some one time setup
which was causing the problem.

Comment: @YashotejaPrabhu: +1 Thanks for your comment. I am running Texmaker on Windows 8 and had to run the whole program as an Administrator to get around this error. Just posting in case this helps others.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the following helps.

1. You can try to regenerate the format files inside the command line window of Windows. Therefor type `initexmf --dump` or just the format for pdfLaTeX `initexmf --dump=pdflatex`.
2. You can use the frontend of MikTeX: <kbd>Start</kbd> => <kbd>Programs</kbd> => <kbd>MiKTeX 2.9</kbd> => <kbd>Maintenance</kbd> => <kbd>Settings</kbd> and *Update Formats*:

> [image]