# TeXlipse cannot build

Tags: miktex, compiling, texlipse

On my new computer I cannot get TeXlipse to build. I'm on a Windows 7 Machine using MikTeX portable. I keep getting the error

```
pdflatex.exe: the memory dump file could not be found.
```

This does not appear to be a problem with MikTeX as I can compile from a different editor (Texmaker). I also re-installed MikTeX, and this didn't work. In addition, I've re-installed TeXlipse, and I still get the same problem. In short, I have tried everything. All suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been here before, but not exclusive to a single editor. 
You might try [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114248/error-when-compiling-pdflatex) (regenerate the format files)  or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81739/the-memory-dump-file-could-not-be-found) (change permissions / run it as an admin). The second one seems more likely to solve your problem.

You could also try to use the non-portable version of Miktex.

Comment: Thanks for this. Regenerating the format files does not work. I'm running MikTex as admin, and it works okay with other editors. So I think this is specific to texlipse.

Comment: I'd been using MiKTex portable. I downloaded and installed MikTex and likewise this didn't work. Again, just to recap, MikTex works fine with other editors, so this must be a texlipse issue

Comment: Did you check/adjust the Texlipse Builder Settings after re-installing? And did you run Texlipse as Admin too?

Comment: Hi. Yes, the builder settings were correct, and I was running as admin.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. I think it has something to do with file system permissions (see eg [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex)), but that is just a guess. A workaround may be to use another TeX distribution instead of MiKTeX: TeXLive.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'm really puzzled by this error and have tried everything. I'm now using LaTeXTools (via sublime text) which works fine.