# disruption of pdflatex after updating miktex 2.9

Tags: miktex, windows, miktex-update

The whole problem started from the point that I wanted to compile something with `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTex` on my windows 10 from `Tex Studio` by `MikTex 2.9`.

I'd just received a `utf-8` error, so according to some advice on `TEX.SE`, I'd decided to update my `MikTex`. I made it successfully, as one can see following log after update:

```
MiKTeX Update Wizard Report

Version: 2.9.4913
Date: Thursday, January 26, 2017
Time: 19:45:08
starting package maintenance...

installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"

package repository: http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

lightweight database digest: 524ebef2c248e9780b88a6c588605d24

going to download 18543326 bytes

going to install 91 file(s) (12 package(s))

going to remove 1308 file(s) (45 package(s))

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-bibarts-bin.tar.lzma...

123555 bytes, 504.85 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

6513392 bytes, 1336.29 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-dvips.tar.lzma...

3101 bytes, 151.42 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-dvips.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-epstopdf-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

28432 bytes, 645.71 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-epstopdf-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-fontconfig.tar.lzma...

3555 bytes, 192.87 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-fontconfig.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-int-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

5607529 bytes, 1095.88 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-int-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-md5-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

7385 bytes, 240.40 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-md5-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-mpmcli-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

1770005 bytes, 820.37 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-mpmcli-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-tdsutil-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

51218 bytes, 847.76 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-tdsutil-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-ucrt-bin.tar.lzma...

446760 bytes, 1407.38 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-ucrt-bin.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-vc140-bin.tar.lzma...

2275432 bytes, 1329.01 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-vc140-bin.tar.lzma...

downloading http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-xindy-bin.tar.lzma...

1712962 bytes, 1437.13 KB/Sec

extracting files from miktex-xindy-bin.tar.lzma...

removing package hoekwater...

removing package miktex-bibtex-base...

removing package miktex-bibtex8bit-base...

removing package miktex-cweb-base...

removing package miktex-dvipdfm-base-2.7...

removing package miktex-dvipdfmx-base-2.7...

removing package miktex-dvips-base...

removing package miktex-dvips-doc...

removing package miktex-etex-base-2.9...

removing package miktex-fontconfig-base...

removing package miktex-fontname-base...

removing package miktex-freetype-base...

removing package miktex-freetype-bin-2.9...

removing package miktex-ghostscript-base-2.9...

removing package miktex-ghostscript-bin-2.9...

removing package miktex-graphics-bin-2.9...

removing package miktex-gsf2pk-base...

removing package miktex-hyph-french...

removing package miktex-hyph-german...

removing package miktex-hyph-usenglish...

removing package miktex-icu-bin-2.9...

removing package miktex-latex-config-2.9...

removing package miktex-luatex-base...

removing package miktex-makeindex-base...

removing package miktex-metafont-base...

removing package miktex-metafont-misc...

removing package miktex-metapost-base-2.7...

removing package miktex-mft-base...

removing package miktex-mtx-bin...

removing package miktex-pdftex-base-2.9...

removing package miktex-pdftex-doc-2.6...

removing package miktex-pmx-bin...

removing package miktex-poppler-base...

removing package miktex-psutils-base...

removing package miktex-qt4-bin-2.9...

removing package miktex-tex-base...

removing package miktex-tex-misc...

removing package miktex-texinfo-base...

removing package miktex-texinfo-bin-2.9...

removing package miktex-texworks-doc-2.9...

removing package miktex-vc100-bin...

removing package miktex-xdvipdfmx-bin-2.9...

removing package miktex-xetex-base...

removing package pdftex-def...

removing package vertex...

mpm --register-components --verbose --admin:
configuring fontconfig\config\fonts.conf


registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core.dll


registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core-PS.dll


registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll


registering C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager-PS.dll


log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (mpmcli).


log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.


initexmf --update-fndb --verbose --admin:
Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Matiking\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...


Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Matiking\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...


Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...


Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...


initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose --admin:
Making format links...


Making script links...


  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-taskbar-icon.exe


  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-update.exe


initexmf --mkmaps --mklangs --verbose --admin:
Entering administrative mode...


Parsing config file "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\dvips35.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\pdftex35.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\dvipdfm35.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\ps2pk35.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\cm.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\cmextra.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\cyrillic.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\euler.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\dvips\eurosym\eurosym.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\latxfont.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\rsfs\rsfs.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\sansmathaccent\sansmathaccent.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\symbols.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\dvips\tipa\tipa.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\xypic\xypic.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\charter.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\fpls.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\lm\lm.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\pazo.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\dvips\pslatex\pcrr8rn.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\psnfss.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\rsfso\rsfso.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\avantgar\uag.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\bookman\ubk.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\courier\ucr.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\helvetic\uhv.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\ncntrsbk\unc.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\palatino\upl.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\symbol\usy.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\times\utm.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\utopia.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\zapfchan\uzc.map"...


Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\zapfding\uzd.map"...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\ps2pk.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\download35.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\builtin35.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_t1.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_pk.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_ndl14.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_dl14.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_dl14.map...


Writing C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_ndl14.map...


Copying C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_t1.map


     to C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts.map...


Copying C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_dl14.map


     to C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm.map...


Copying C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_dl14.map


     to C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex.map...


C:/Windows/Fonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1129 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 5 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/adobe: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 2 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/adobe/courier: skipping, existing cache is valid: 6 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/adobe/utopia: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/groff: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/hoekwater: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 3 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/hoekwater/mflogo: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/hoekwater/misc: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/hoekwater/rsfs: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 7 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 6 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm: skipping, existing cache is valid: 75 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cmextra: skipping, existing cache is valid: 15 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cyrillic: skipping, existing cache is valid: 5 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler: skipping, existing cache is valid: 22 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/latxfont: skipping, existing cache is valid: 14 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols: skipping, existing cache is valid: 12 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cbcoptic: skipping, existing cache is valid: 2 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/eurosym: skipping, existing cache is valid: 12 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm: skipping, existing cache is valid: 92 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/rsfs: skipping, existing cache is valid: 3 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/tipa: skipping, existing cache is valid: 68 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/xypic: skipping, existing cache is valid: 23 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 10 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/avantgar: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/bookman: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/courier: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic: skipping, existing cache is valid: 14 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/ncntrsbk: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/palatino: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/symbol: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/times: skipping, existing cache is valid: 4 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/zapfchan: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/urw/zapfding: skipping, existing cache is valid: 1 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 1 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public: skipping, existing cache is valid: 0 fonts, 1 dirs


C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm: skipping, existing cache is valid: 72 fonts, 0 dirs


C:/Users/Matiking/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fontconfig/cache: cleaning cache directory


C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\fc-cache.EXE: succeeded


Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
```

Then, as I've found that not only `LuaLaTeX` and `XeLaTeX` still don't work, but my `pdfLaTeX` has been also corrupted and the compiler said: `MiKTeX209-jpeg.dll is missing`. Based on answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345900/miktex209-jpeg-dll-is-missing), I did installed all `\Miktex X.X executables (windows-x86)` from package manager and even synchronized packages.

Then, `initexmf` had been raised for two of packages and I did what people have asserted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114248/error-when-compiling-pdflatex) to `Update Formats`. But:

[image]

And as I clicked `Yes`, nothing happened, but an empty `Transcript` window.

Then (after next try to compile) the error changed to:

[image]

So, I tried the answers of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98129/texstudio-compile-error-could-not-start-the-command-pdflatex-exe), by direct addressing `pdfLaTeX` from `Configure TeX Studio` as `"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" %.tex`.

Now I've faced up with this error: `Error: Command crashed: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" "root".tex`

[image]

Addition of options `-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode` to command makes to difference in the error, as well.

As I even try `pdflatex sample2e` from windows command prompt:

[image]

The worse thing is that when I switched my editor to `TeX Maker`, a new error has been raised different with the previous one in `TeX Studio`!!!!!:

[image]

I'm terribly stuck here...

Any help?

Comment: Run the update utility again (I think many packages still have to be updated).

Comment: @Arzigoglu According to the corresponding wizard, they've been completely updated... Even tried again... Nothing happened.

Comment: Start the package manager and install all the `miktex-...` packages.

Comment: @Arzigoglu: Thanks... Done... But error is the same as before...

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same issue.

After uninstalling and reinstalling the miktek-pdftek... packages, I manually copied pdflatex from pdftex using the following command in a terminal (in admin mode).

```
copy miktex-pdftex.exe pdflatex.exe
```

It solved the issue for me.

I found this solution here if it may help you :
https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2499/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.